# Change align of icons

Tags: gnome, icons, ubuntu-10.04, notifications, alignment

Using Ubuntu 10.4. How can I change aligment of icons to right in Notification Area Applet?

Answer (score 1):

Anything in the GNOME toolbars can be rearranged. Just right click on an applet and unlock it, then you can drag it around.